# Reading Checkbox FormControl value in Angular Reactive Form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have the following code

```
if (this.myForm.value['isDefault'] === true)
```

Where isDefault is a checkbox FormControl. Now if the checkbox is checked I am expecting this.myForm.value['isDefault'] will result in true. When I alert this, it indeed shows true but this comparison does not result in true.

Comment: Can you try `console.log(typeof  this.myForm.value['isDefault'])` ? And show the output

Comment: Can you post the all of the code surrounding this logic ? For example how you update your model when someone clicks on the checkbox and so one. Otherwise it is difficult to help you with just those info.

Comment: @R3tep Its boolean

Comment: Can you show more code and HTML? A checkbox (or any form element)'s value is not always the same as it's checked state.

Comment: Its working. I did not test properly. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need recheck your form and code in TS file. I reproduce it still work correctly.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <form [formGroup]="theForm" (submit)="check()">
            Check? <input type='checkbox' formControlName="firstCheck"/>
  <input type="submit" value="check">
    </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

TS

```
export class AppComponent {

  theForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.theForm = fb.group({
      firstCheck: false
    })
  }

  check() {
    console.log(this.theForm.value['firstCheck'] === true)
  }
}
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/checkbox-reactive-aagwtp?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

If you want a value of a form control , you can also access using `form.get('key').value`.

I forked @Hien Nguyen's stckblitz :

Refer : https://stackblitz.com/edit/checkbox-reactive-hdwhsj?file=app/app.component.ts

So i would use : `this.myForm.get('isDefault').value`